# Is there any IdentityUserRole Store in asp identity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I try to customize IdentityUserRole like this

```
public partial class MyUserRoles : IdentityUserRole
{
    pulic bool isAdminUser{set;get;}
}
```

after that i want to add an object

```
{
  ...
        MyUserRoles userRole=new MyUserRoles();
        userRole.UserId = user.Id;
        userRole.RoleId = rolemanager.id;
        userRole.isAdminUser = true;
}
```

my question is how to add this userRole to the userRoleTable

Comment: the problem not with the var name ? the problem with the way that you can customize IdentityUserRole, otherwise the problem already been solved thanks.

Comment: I don't think you're hearing what I'm saying.  IdentityUserRole is a class that solely exists to show the relationship between a user and a role.  Administrator should be a role unto itself, not a bool in that table.  That's a totally crazy design that doesn't make any sense, even though you *can* do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<SecuHostUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("SecuHostEntitiesSecurity")
    {
    }
    new public DbSet<MyUserRoles> UserRoles { set; get; }
} 

ApplicationDbContext context=  new ApplicationDbContext();
context.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
context.savechange
```